# Performing multiline xss

Tags: xss

I am playing one pentesting game theres a task where i need to perform multi line xss to print cookies.

I was able to make xss that print "x" because one line is too short for entire command so this works `"><script>alert("x")</script>`( this is max length of field and we have three fields available)

But i need to use this `"><script>alert(document.cookie)</script>` and dont know how to modify it for three fields that i have for this task.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Security.SE. Without additional information it's hard to answer this question. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common way to do this is to span the payload across multiple parameters.For example imagine there are three parameter's param1,param2,param3.

```
param1=<script><then begin comment block>

param2=<end comment block>alert(document.cookie)<start comment block>

param3=<end comment block><script>
```

**So the general idea is to comment out the middle that way you can stretch the payload, whenever there is a (number of character restriction).**

Adjust the payload according to the number of allowed characters in the parameter's.